# Функция записи значения в файл

Tags: java, android, файлы

Нужно написать функцию `saveToFile(String filename, String str)` которая должна записать в файл с значениемаргумента `filename` значение аргумента `str`
Для записи нужно использовать класс `PrintWriter`.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделайте для себя. Я использую так. Передаю активность потому что находится в другом месте. Можете убрать `static`, убрать из аргументов `FragmentActivity fragmentActivity`, и подставить свой активити,фрагмент.

```
  // сохранение файла
    public static void saveText(String s, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, String file){

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            fos = fragmentActivity.openFileOutput(file, fragmentActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(s.getBytes());
            fos.close();

             Toast.makeText(fragmentActivity, "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {

            Toast.makeText(fragmentActivity, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(fos!=null)
                    fos.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                Log.e("TEST2", ex.getMessage());

                // Toast.makeText(fragmentActivity, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

И чтение из файла

```
 // открытие файла
public static String openText(FragmentActivity activity, String file) {

    FileInputStream fin = null;
    Player player;
    try {
        try {
            fin = activity.openFileInput(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            bytes = new byte[fin.available()];
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fin.read(bytes);
        fin.close();
        String text = new String(bytes);
        return text;
    } catch (IOException ex) {

         Toast.makeText(activity, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("TEST", ex.getMessage());
    } finally {

        try {
            if (fin != null)
                fin.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("TEST", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Благадарю, все работает