# Сохранение и вывод данных

Tags: java, android, файлы

Есть 3 поля с даными, вводимыми пользователями: имя, дата рождения, место рождения. надо записать эти данные в файл а потом из файла запихнуть все в listview.
Как сохранить эти поля в файл (группой по 3 поля) и потом вывести их так же раздельно, чтобы это была не одна строка??

Comment: подробнее напишите, а то ни черта не понятно

Comment: есть три поля: имя, дата рождения, место рождения. надо записать эти данные в файл а потом из файла запихнуть все в listview. не могу дойти сам до того как это сделать

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `SharedPreferences` - более-менее внятные примеры [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php)

Comment: @Barmaley мне нужно именно сохранение в файл типа txt. если можно как-то с примером

Answer (score 1):

Не давно отвечал на похожий ответ.[Чтение и запись в файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829336/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/829375#829375). Думаю он вам подойдет. 
Там я передаю `String` в качестве данных, которые хочу сохранить в файл. Вам предлагаю эти три поля объединить в класс. А потом с помощью Json записывать данные. На примере использую класс `Player`, вы можете использовать любой друг класс и с разной структурой.

Допустим ваш класс

```
class Player {
String name;
String date;
String city;

public Player(String name, String date, String city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.city = city;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
```

}

Создавать объекты класса я думаю вы умеете создавать. Если вам нужно несколько классов, вы можете его обернуть в другой класс или использовать списки.

К примеру мы создали объект класса Player. И тут мы с помощью `Gson` конвертируем его в json-строку чтоб сохранить в файл.

```
String s = new Gson().toJson(player);
```

Для считывания данных

```
player = new Gson().fromJson(text, Player.class);
```

Конечно подключить библиотеку. Возможно вышла уже новая версия.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Это один из вариантов реализации. На данный момент такой вариант использую у себя в приложение

Comment: могу попросить вас реализовать вот это: 3 поля ввода, эти данные внести в текстовый файл, и потом вывест их в 3 переменные?? если вас это не затруднит, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Только если вечером, добавлю. Ну остальную реализацию сами

Comment: хорошо, спасибо